# How to save a text file with noeol and in dos format using vi on a linux system

Tags: unix, dos, vi

I am running the IBAMR model (a set of codes for solving immersed boundary problems) on x86_64 GNU/Linux.
The startup configuration file is called input2d.
When I open it with vi, I find:

"input2d" [noeol][dos] 251L, 11689C

If I compile the IBAMR model without saving input2d, it compiles and runs fine.
However, if I save input2d, the compiler crashes, saying:

```
Warning in input2d at line 251 column 5 : Illegal character token in input
```

Clearly this has something to do with unix adding a newline to the end of the file.
Here's my question:
How do I save this file in dos format AND without a trailing newline in vi on a unix system?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `vim -b <file>` or `:set binary` to tell vim not to append an newline at the end of the file. From `:help binary`:

> When writing a file the `<EOL>` for the last line is only written if
>       there was one in the original file (normally Vim appends an `<EOL>` to
>       the last line if there is none; this would make the file longer).  See
>       the 'endofline' option.

Answer (score 0):

There's a script for this that I found on Vim Tips:

http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Preserve_missing_end-of-line_at_end_of_text_files

It automatically enables "binary" if there was no eol, but ensures the original line-endings are preserved for the rest of the file.